# django direction to \ wrong URL href

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

My url is being directed to the wrong location. The `href` when used in `search.html` is directing me to the right location, but when the same url I am using in `categories.html`, it is giving an error page of wrong location.

File `categories.html`

```html
<p class="card-text"><a href="results/detail/" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{news.title}}</a></p>
```

I have to get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newspaperapp/results/detail/1` but instead of that it is directing me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newspaperapp/category/results/detail/`.

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
app_name = 'newspaperapp'
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from .views import SearchView
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('results/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('results/detail/<int:id>',views.detail,name='detail'),
    path('category/<int:id>',views.category,name='category'),
]
```

Comment: Firstly you have no pattern that will match this url `href="results/detail/"`. Secondly relative urls that do not start in a leading `/` mean they are relative from the current page, if they start with a leading `/` they are from the domain. So it should be `href="/results/detail/"` (which will still give an error due to there being no id or number in this url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here pass related news `id` and add `'/'` in href.

your main **urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns=[
   ...
   path('newspaperapp/',include('newspaperapp.urls')),        
]
```

**newspaperapp/urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns=[
            ...
  path('results/detail/<int:id>/',views.detail,name='detail'),
 ]
```

**categories.html:**

```
<p class="card-text"><a href="{% url 'detail' news.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{news.title}}</a></p>
```

**or**

```
<p class="card-text"><a href="/newspaperapp/results/detail/{{news.id}}/" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{news.title}}</a></p>
```